# Looking for a programable nanny cam

Tags: camera, ip-camera

I have a Foscam 1918w, which I created a custom interface for. The process wasn't cool, and it wasn't transparent about how to reprogram the interface. I also had to overhaul the front-end, which was super insecure. Now, I'm in the market for another panning and tilting nanny cam, with or without mic, and the ability to write and or reprogram the device is a key feature.  (When I bought the foscam, I misread/ interpreted the name as FOSS-Cam, and thought it would be an open hardware project. That was a mistake.)

I am looking for a panning, tilting, network camera, that is based on open hardware, or at the very least, open source software. If anyone knows of products like that, I would be very interested.

Comment: It looks like you need some opensource software. Does this fit the bill? https://zoneminder.com/

Comment: is there a list of hardware there some place?

Comment: Their website says it the software works with any camera. On their webpage...